# To delete the common files from two folders

Tags: ubuntu, command-line

i have two folders and in those folder i have some common files. now i want to delete the common files from the first folder.
 like i have two folder name folder1 and folder2.
  now in folder1 i have a , b , c file and in folder2 i have c ,b w, d files. i want to delete the common files means b and c file from the folder1.

i can found the common files by the command line

```
diff -ur folder1 folder2
```

but i cant delete the common files from the first folder in ubuntu commandline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got a simpler solution:

```
for f in `ls -1 folder1`; do rm folder2/$f; done;
```

Comment: Doesn't work with file names containing spaces. Tried `for f in `ls -1 folder1`; do rm "folder2/$f"; done;` but didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

```
find FIRSTDIR SECONDDIR -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec basename {} \; | \
    sort | \
    uniq -d | \
    sed 's_.*_rm FIRSTDIR/\0_' | \
    sh
```

1. So it first checks `FIRSTDIR` and `SECONDDIR` for any file(s) (and only in the exact directory, not recursive), then remove it's path part.
2. Sorts the previous output
3. Remove the items which appears only once (only non uniq elements remaining)
4. generates an `rm` line from it
5. which is executed, and I'd *do recommend* to leave out the last line first to check what would be done.

Comment: find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument -type, but options are not positional (-maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.

Comment: That's only a warning. So switch the `-type f` and `-maxdepth 1` params if you want to.

Comment: Got a super simple solution... `for f in \`ls -1 folder1\`; do rm folder2/$f; done;`